# Generating Random Long value in Java

Tags: java, random

I am trying to generate two  9 digit long random long value in Java using the below code:

```
for (int i =0;i<2;i++) {                
    String axisIdStr = Long.toString((long)(System.nanoTime() * (Math.random() * 1000)));
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@ axisIdStr "+axisIdStr);
    String axId = axisIdStr.substring((axisIdStr.length() -9), axisIdStr.length()) ;
}
```

But when I run this in windows, i get two different numbers where as when run in mac, I get same two numbers. Why is this happening ?
Can you suggest a better way to generate the long values?

Comment: What's wrong with generating random integer and casting it to long?

Comment: Why not just use a `Random`? It has `.nextLong()`...

Comment: I wanted to write my own function. Thats why I did not use .nextLong. @fge.

Comment: @fge. Will .nextLong always give me a value which will have more than 9 digits ?

Comment: @RahulGoyal is this homework? if not, why don't use an existing mechanism as `fge` proposed ?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov.. its not a homework, my requirement is to generate a 9 digit random number each time. Will .nextLong always give me a value which will have more than 9 digits ?

Comment: It won't; it is random (well, pseudo random) as the name says. Note that since you use 9 digits, an int is enough, so you can just use `random.nextInt(1_000_000_000)`, which is guaranteed to return an int between 0 and 10^9-1

Comment: @fge. I need 9 digits each time...

Comment: Well, 0 is a digit, you know

Comment: @fge..i know 0 is a digit...what if .nextInt() returns 123. how will this be 9 digit ?

Comment: Your current code may just throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, if the `Math.random()` call returns a small enough value.

Comment: @DavidWallace..thats for pointing that out.

Comment: on a very fast/imprecise machine, rapid calls to `System.nanoTime()` and `(Math.random()` will yield identical results.

Comment: @RahulGoyal: trivial, use `random.nextInt(900_000_000) + 100_000_000`

Comment: @njzk2..looks like a good solution..

Comment: @njzk2 If you make that an answer, I'll upvote it.  It's definitely the best way.

Comment: is 000000001 valid for your requirements?

Comment: @Palcente. no..that would not work..

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement you need to generate 9 digit random numbers. As in the comment suggested  you can do it using random.Below I have just given one solution to generate random number between two numbers.

```
long lowerLimit = 123456712L;
long upperLimit = 234567892L;
Random r = new Random();
long number = lowerLimit+((long)(r.nextDouble()*(upperLimit-lowerLimit)));
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You could create an array a[] of int of size 9, and populate with random integers 0-9. Then sum the array up multiplying accordingly.

```
a[8]*1 + a[7]*10 + a[6]*100 ...
```

You need to make sure that a[0] only takes digits 1-9 tho...

To get even more random sequence, you Ideally should work on Strings, then you would be able to get 0 on the start position of your random "string", it won't be a number.

Or maybe generate somthing pseudo random and strip last 9 digits out of it.

That's the DIY version of what you could accomplish with what's already out there...

Regards

Comment: why complicate things that much?